# php textfile=file("filepath.txt") - how to return the file array?

Tags: php, file, return-type

After my last question regarding this was completely flawed, a new attempt. The old question will be deleted by moderators asap.

I´m calling  a function gather_info($host_object) from the index.php. This function reads 
in text-files using the file()-method. When I use print_r inside the function to print out 
the contents for debugging purposes it is working fine.

But the (in this case) 3 variables cannot be accessed from the index.php. They are undefined. 
I tried playing with the 'return' values but it´s just not working.

index.php:

```
gather_info($host_object);
for($i=0;$i<count($in);$i++){

}
```

gather_info.php

```
function gather_info($host_object){

return  $in=file("./data/traceroute/traceroute_$host_object.txt",true);
return   $in2=file("./data/hosts/hosts_$host_object.txt",true);
return  $in3=file("./data/ping/pings_$host_object.txt",true);

}
```

When I read in the files within the index.php it is also working fine. Any hint ?

Comment: 3x return ? Is this possible ? Does this make sense ?

Comment: No it does not. Was a long day. I had return array($in1,in*,...) before but didn´t know how to access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` aborts execution of the function and returns immediately the calling context. You cannot have multiple returns like that - it's literally impossible for the 2nd and further returns to **EVER** get executed.

You can have a single `return` call and return an array of elements, e.g.

```
function gather_info(...) {
   ...
   return array($in, $in2, $in3);
}

$foo = gather_info(...);
$in = $foo[0];
$in2 = $foo[1];
etc...
```

Comment: OK. New Question and still paste-mistakes. I had return array(...) before but did not know what to do with it. I´ll give it a try. Thank you !